# UserForm WebBrowser web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have web browser in UserForm and would like to automate the procedure for button in UserForm. So once user clicks button on UserForm with browser window code should do web scraping. This works if it is not in UserForms web browser. So now when this is inside UserForm it does the code until:

```
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    .Document.querySelector("[name=import_budgets]").Click
```

After that I am getting an error on `.Document.querySelector("[name=import_budgets]").Click`. Also web browser is not "refreshing" (moving to next page), I see it has been done `.Document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").Click` and moved to next page only after receiving an error. Web browser do operations but they are not visible to user, probably that's why it can't proceed to next operation. How to make this work correct?

```
   With LCountry.WebBrowser1

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AL21").Value = 2 Then

    .Document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").Click

    Else

    .Document.querySelector(".data .a_1_610").Click

    End If

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    .Document.querySelector("[name=import_budgets]").Click

'Unload IE

    If Err <> 0 Then

       MsgBox "There was an error running the code. Check your Internet and VPN connection. Please try one more time!"
       Else

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: What is `LCountry`? What is `WebBrowser1`? Is part of your code missing?

Comment: `LCountry` is UserForm name and `WebBrowser1`is web browser in UserForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by adding:

```
    While .Busy
      DoEvents
    Wend
    While .ReadyState <> 4
      DoEvents
    Wend
```

To each Web scraping operation in code.